# Workaround for Jenkins shared library cumbersome syntax when using Groovy classes?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Say I have a Jenkins shared library. I call the object this way in my pipeline

```
@Library(shared-lib) _
import com.company.Greeter

node("buildNode") {
  def obj = new Greeter(this)
  obj.printMsg()
}
```

See where I pass the `this` pointer to the constructor?

Now here's my class in `src/com/company/Greeter.groovy`.

```
package com.company

class Greeter implements Serializable {
  private def jfile = null // Jenkinsfile client
  private String msg = "Hello world!"

  Greeter(final def jfile) {
    this.jfile = jfile
  }

  def printMsg()
    jfile.println msg
  }
}
```

See in the function `printMsg()` how I had to use `jfile.println msg` to actually print the string on the console? Just using `println msg` doesn't print the message.

I have used the same `jfile.*` syntax to use any plugin. For example

```
jfile.dir() {} instead of just dir() {}
jfile.sh() instead of just sh()
etc
```

Anyway to avoid this ugly and cumbersome syntax? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid passing the `this` reference to every class instance (`def obj = new Greeter(this)`) and simplify the syntax by using the [Groovy's MetaObject Protocol (MOP)](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/lang/MetaObjectProtocol.html).

That is inspired from "**[Metaprogramming in Groovy](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-metaprogramming)**" from **[Anshul Bansal](https://github.com/SmartyAnsh)**.

You can apply a change in the runtime metaclass of your objects so that every method not found in your object will be delegated to the `steps` object (i.e. the `this` used before in `Greeter(this)`), which contains all the Jenkins steps.
The steps object in Jenkins refers to the script context, which contains all the steps that Jenkins provides for Pipeline scripts. These steps include methods like `sh`, `echo`, `dir`, `git`, `docker`, `node` and many others.

To implement that delegation, we are using:

- [`methodMissing`](https://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_methodmissing), which intercepts a call for any missing method, thereby avoiding the `MissingMethodException`, and
- [`propertyMissing`](https://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_propertymissing), which avoids the `MissingPropertyException` when we try to access an undefined property of a Groovy class.

First, you need to create a base class that will handle the delegation:

```
package com.company

import groovy.lang.MissingMethodException

class JenkinsBase implements Serializable {
    protected transient steps

    JenkinsBase(steps) {
        this.steps = steps
    }

    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        try {
            steps."$name"(*args)
        } catch (MissingMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Method $name not found in steps", e)
        }
    }

    def propertyMissing(String name) {
        steps."$name"
    }
}
```

Then, you extend this base class for your `Greeter` class:

```
package com.company

class Greeter extends JenkinsBase {
    private String msg = "Hello world!"

    Greeter(steps) {
        super(steps)
    }

    def printMsg() {
        println msg
    }
}
```

And finally, use the new `Greeter` class in your Jenkinsfile:

```
@Library('shared-lib') _

import com.company.Greeter

node("buildNode") {
    def obj = new Greeter(this)
    obj.printMsg()
}
```

That way, all the Jenkins steps are available in the class without the need to prefix them with `jfile`. For instance, `dir() {}`, `sh()`, `println msg`, etc. should work as expected.

In a shared library context, these modifications to the metaclass should not affect other builds though because every build uses a fresh class loader.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the answer, I will definitely try this.